# Locate popular strings with PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, full-text-search, postgresql-9.6, tsvector

I have a bunch of text rows in a PostgreSQL table and I am trying to find common strings.

For example, let's say I have a basic table like:

```
CREATE TABLE a (id serial, value text);
INSERT INTO a (value) VALUES
    ('I go to the movie theater'), 
    ('New movie theater releases'), 
    ('Coming out this week at your local movie theater'),
    ('New exposition about learning disabilities at the children museum'),
    ('The genius found in learning disabilities')
;
```

I am trying to locate popular strings like `movie theater` and `learning disabilities` across all the rows (the goal is to show a list of "trending" strings king of like Twitter "Trends")

I use full text search and I have tried to use `ts_stat` combined with `ts_headline` but the results are quite disappointing.

Any thoughts? thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no ready-to-use Posgres text search feature to find most popular phrases. For two-words phrases you can use `ts_stat()` to find most popular words, eliminate particles, prepositions etc, and cross join these words to find most popular pairs.

For an actual data you would want to change values marked as `--> parameter.` The query may be quite expensive on a larger dataset.

```
with popular_words as (
    select word
    from ts_stat('select value::tsvector from a')
    where nentry > 1                                --> parameter
    and not word in ('to', 'the', 'at', 'in', 'a')  --> parameter
)
select concat_ws(' ', a1.word, a2.word) phrase, count(*) 
from popular_words as a1
cross join popular_words as a2
cross join a
where value ilike format('%%%s %s%%', a1.word, a2.word)
group by 1
having count(*) > 1                                 --> parameter
order by 2 desc;


        phrase         | count 
-----------------------+-------
 movie theater         |     3
 learning disabilities |     2
(2 rows)
```

Comment: Thanks klin, that sounds like a good approach, I will test that!

Comment: For future visitors, you can use `to_tsvector(value)` instead of `value::tsvector` to avoid syntax issues if your strings include semicolons in them.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like:
`SELECT * FROM a WHERE value LIKE '%movie theater%';`

This would find rows which match the pattern 'movie theater' somewhere in the value column (and could include any number of characters before or after it).

Comment: HI @Lionel, I have no knowledge that `movie theater` is a popular string, that the information I am searching for

Comment: I see. Can you provide a bit more information about what you mean by `popular string`? For example are you looking for popular keywords, or perhaps phrases? are you looking for the most popular, or is there some threshold at which a keyword or phrase is sufficiently popular?

Comment: Popular keywords like Twitter does for "Trends" for example. My goal is to find the most popular ones (top 10 for example)