# Count unique entries for ts_stat count in full text search

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm struggling with using ts_stat to get the number of unique occurrences of tags in a table and sort them by the highest count. 
What I need though is to only count each entry one time so that only unique entries are counted. I tried group by and distinct but nothing is working for me.

e.g. table

```
user_id | tags         | post_date
===================================
2       | dog cat      | 1580049400
2       | dog          | 1580039400
3       | dog          | 1580038400
3       | dog dog cat  | 1580058400
4       | dog horse    | 1580028400
```

Here is the current query

```
SELECT word, ndoc, nentry
FROM   ts_stat($$SELECT to_tsvector('simple', tags) FROM tags WHERE post_date > 1580018400$$) 
ORDER  BY ndoc DESC
LIMIT  10;
```

Right now this will produce

```
word | ndoc | nentry
====================
dog  | 5    | 6
cat  | 2    | 2
horse| 1    | 1
```

The result I would be looking for is unique counts so no 1 user can count more than once even if they have > 1 entries after a certain date as noted in the post_date condition (Which might be irrelevant). Like below.

```
word | total_count_per_user
===========================
dog  | 3    (because there are 3 unique users with this term)
cat  | 2    (because there are 2 unique users with this term)
horse| 1    (because there are 1 unique users with this term)
```

**UPDATE**: I changed the column name to reflect output. The point is no matter how many times a user enters a word. It only needs the unique count per user. e.g. if a user in that scenario creates 100 entries with dog in the text it will only count dog 1 time for that user not 100 counts of dog.

Comment: Your sample data is not sufficient to explain the scenario. Please add all considered columns and your exact required output from the sample data. This would help.

Comment: @mkRabbani Thanks but I mean it pretty much does. That is the scenario. I added the post_date but that is not as relevant. The point is I need to show distinct counts. You see user_id 2 is there twice. So it needs to eliminate 1 of those. But I don't know how to do that with `ts_stat`. that is the problem.

Comment: Your example doesn't define what you want very clearly.  If user_id 3 had another row with "dog dog cat dog butterfly" what then would be your desired output?

Comment: @jjanes I updated the example table. but it would be the same output, 3, because each user can only count once per word found by ts_stat,  You can see my table updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this one was tough. Just in case someone happens to have a similar requirement I was able to get this to work. Seems odd to have to get total with ts_stat then filter it again using distinct, cross join etc so that no matter how many times it finds a word each user only counts once per word. I'm not sure how efficient it will be on a large data set but it yields the expected results.

**UPDATE**: This is works without using a CTE. Also cross join is the key to filtering on user id.

```
SELECT DISTINCT (t.word) as tag, count(DISTINCT h.user_id) as posts 
FROM ts_stat($$SELECT hashtagsearch FROM tagstable WHERE post_date > 1580018400$$) t 
CROSS JOIN tagstable h WHERE hashtagsearch @@ to_tsquery('simple',t.word)
GROUP BY t.word HAVING count(DISTINCT h.user_id) > 1 ORDER BY posts DESC LIMIT 10'
```

This answer helped quite a bit. https://stackoverflow.com/a/42704207/330987

Answer (score 1):

You can use COUNT on DISTINCT value if I get your point correct. The sample query is as below-

```
SELECT tags,COUNT(DISTINCT user_id)
FROM your_table
GROUP BY tags
```

Comment: Thanks but it's not that simple.  this is full text search as there could be multiple words in the column. As shown the query uses ts_stat to get the count of the lexmes already of the most popular word(s).  What I'm trying to do is limit ts_stat to unique rows. It by nature counts all.