# Efficient Popular Words PostgreSQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql, search, indexing, full-text-search

UPDATE: Added 2nd underperforming query

I am trying to write a query that generates the popular words of a large, constantly changing dataset. However, I am having trouble getting useful results or having a query end in a reasonable timeframe.

The problem I am running into is two fold:

1. When I use tsvector with the query below, my results are lexemes, which I do not want to display to the end user.

```
SELECT word, ndoc
FROM
ts_stat($$ SELECT normalized_tsvector FROM activities 
   WHERE
      activities.identifiedat >
      current_timestamp - interval '60 minutes'
   $$)
WHERE word NOT IN ('like', 'to', 'the', 'at', 'in', 'a')
ORDER BY ndoc DESC LIMIT 50
```

This returns lexemes like "peopl" instead of "people" which are not useful.

2. A query I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42704207/1953832) is too slow - even on a sample set of data (700 items) it ran for 20 minutes without returning.

The query that I tried is as follows:

```
with popular_words as (
    select word
    from ts_stat('select normalized_tsvector from activities')
    where nentry > 1
    and not word in ('to', 'the', 'at', 'in', 'a')
)                                              
select concat_ws(' ', a1.word, a2.word) phrase, count(*)
from popular_words as a1        
cross join popular_words as a2
cross join activities                                                                                                   
where normalized ilike format('%%%s %s%%', a1.word, a2.word)
group by 1                                                         
having count(*) > 1
order by 2 desc;
```

**My question is two fold:**

- Is there a way to convert a lexeme back to a word, or at least what words would match? I'm wondering if I can run a separate query to find the most common usages of a word matching given lexeme.
- Is there is a way to improve performance on the second query? Perhaps some sort of indexing?

My table is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS activities (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    document JSONB,
    normalized TEXT,
    identifiedat TIMESTAMP with time zone DEFAULT now(),
    instance VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE activities 
  ADD normalized_tsvector tsvector
    GENERATED ALWAYS AS (to_tsvector('english', normalized)) STORED;


CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS  activities_uri_idx ON activities ( (document->>'id') );

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS activities_published_idx ON activities ( (document->>'published') );
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS activities_identifiedat_idx ON activities (identifiedat);

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS normalized_idx ON activities USING gin(normalized_tsvector);

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS activities_id_idx ON activities (id);
```

Thank you!

Comment: The query you linked to that was too slow doesn't actually do what you want.  You must have modified it, but we don't know how.  Please show us what you actually did.

Comment: @jjanes Good callout, Please see the updated post.

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty easy to get unstemmed words by using the 'simple' configuration, then stem them in english, to find what original word is the most common origin of each stemmed word.  Then join that back to your original query.

```
with t as (SELECT word, ndoc
FROM
ts_stat($$ SELECT normalized_tsvector FROM activities 
   WHERE
      activities.identifiedat >
      current_timestamp - interval '60 minutes'
   $$)
WHERE word NOT IN ('like', 'to', 'the', 'at', 'in', 'a')
ORDER BY ndoc DESC LIMIT 50),
lex as (SELECT distinct on (lexeme) to_tsvector('english',word) as lexeme, word as original_word
FROM
ts_stat($$ SELECT to_tsvector('simple',normalized) FROM activities 
   WHERE
      activities.identifiedat >
      current_timestamp - interval '60 minutes'
   $$)
ORDER BY lexeme, ndoc desc)
select t.*, original_word from t left join lex on (to_tsvector('english',t.word)=lex.lexeme);
```

You are defining your own list of stop words, but that should be unnecessary as 'english' comes with its own list. But I didn't removing that part of your query.

This took about 3.5 seconds to process 52,670 documents containing 2,457,189
individual tokens and 75,732 distinct tokens.  (most distinct tokens were typos, email addresses, urls, or hex digest values--the data is from the body of git commit messages stripped of headers, but they still have bits of cruft)